# Send MySQL data to GRAYLOG server

Tags: mysql, linux, wordpress, audit, graylog

I have audit logs in my Wordpress server and Wordpress keep them in the MySQL server. I need to send these audit logs to Graylog server and I can't find a solution for how I could send MySQL table to Graylog server.

Note: all systems are runing on CentOS 7 .

Comment: For reference: https://community.graylog.org/t/send-wordpress-server-audit-logs-to-graylog/2824

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, you can use a Logstash JDBC input to read the audit logs from the MySQL database, possibly filter them, and finally send them to Graylog with a GELF output.

- https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/6.0/plugins-inputs-jdbc.html
- https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/6.0/plugins-outputs-gelf.html